# Refactoring for for loop and error(Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type String to Integer)

Tags: java, refactoring

This method is to check duplicated variables.
And recently I found out about a new syntax:

```
for-loop(String s: List) like this.
```

And I tried to apply that new instruction to my current code, but it causes an error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type String to Integer
```

1. I want to refactor my code (please advise me)
2. Why for syntax ( for (Integer i : duplicateList) //  for (Integer k 
   :checkList) ) have the error? is there any way to apply that new syntax? or any other advise?

This is my original code:

```
public List<String> checkDuplicateInArray(List<String> checkList) {

    Set<String> unique = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> duplicate = new HashSet<>();

    for (String val : checkList) {
        (unique.contains(val) ? duplicate : unique).add(val);
    }

    List<String> duplicateList = new ArrayList<>(duplicate);

    //**************I want to change this part..*************
    for (int i = 0; i < duplicateList.size(); i++) {
        int a = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < checkList.size(); k++) {
            if (duplicateList.get(i).trim().equals(checkList.get(k).trim())) {
                if(a!=0){

                    checkList.set(k, checkList.get(k) + a);
                    }
                a++;
            }
        }
    }       
    return checkList;
}
```

This is the way I changed it (which produces the error):

**Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type String to Integer**

```
    for (Integer i : duplicateList) {
        int a = 0;

        for (Integer k :checkList) {
            if (duplicateList.get(i).trim().equals(checkList.get(k).trim())) {
                if(a!=0){

                    checkList.set(k, checkList.get(k) + a);
                    }
                a++;

            }
        }
    }
```

Any help please?

Comment: `for (Integer i : duplicateList) {` since `duplicateList` is a `List<String>` what did you think would happen here? Just make `i` a `String` and use it instead of `duplicateList.get(i)` further down. And maybe give it a more significant name, while you're at it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html This should answer every question you have :)

Comment: Your sets are of String not Integer, either change the sets type to Integer or change the loops type to Strings

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca i see, thanks . that means i only can apply for (Integer i : integerlist)?

Comment: @ Sofo Gial  thanks!!! i will check it

Comment: No, it means you're using the wrong type for `i` and `k`. See @turamarth's answer

Comment: Considering how you use the values do the lists actually contain Strings or Integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared:

```
Set<String> duplicate = new HashSet<>();
```

But you tried to iterate on Integer:

```
for (Integer i : duplicateList) {
```

So you naturally must respect the type:

```
for (String s : duplicateList) {
```